# Multiple subnets communicating with Server

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

I have three clients, each one in a different subnet like this:

Client 1: 192.168.2.11/26  (network .2.0 ; broadcast .2.63)
Client 2: 192.168.2.72/26  (network .2.64 ; broadcast .2.127)
Client 3: 192.168.2.133/26 (network .2.128 ; broadcast .2.191)

I want all of the clients to be able to communicate with a file server.
Communication between clients is not required.

The question is, what IP/subnet/network should I assign to the server to achieve this goal?

Do I need a router in the middle to be able to get all three clients to communicate with the server?

Or there is a much simpler way? Communication needs to be both ways. Client-Server; Server-Client.

I would greatly appreciate some kind of help.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes, its a home-school assignment! I can use any configuration I want.Though the clients still need to be in different subnets.

Comment: Just for your information - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.  Can you explain what you've tried or what you think the solution is, then we can give feedback?  Giving you the answer won't help you much.

Comment: Okay, I am rather new to this forum. I understand the rules. I know that this will work with a router,having routes to all the subnets but I want to use only a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a router  (or layer 3 switch) to allow each subnet to communicate with the server.  You can use supernetting to minimize the number of routes you need to create for the file server.

Answer (score 0):

You either need a router **or** you need to assign multiple networks to the file server.

This is possible, even with a single physical NIC.
Exactly how you do that depends on the OS running on your server.